# create text box search for multi select field in view

Tags: views, search

I have a custom content type in my drupal installation called Stores. While creating a new content for Stores I have a checkbox where I can select multiple zip codes.

I have created a view with my store listing and I want to add an option for the user to have a text box where s/he can enter a zip code and the store list gets filtered based on this. I have exposed the zip code field as a filter in the view. However since this is a multi-select field the filter shows up as a drop down to the user instead of a text box. I want a empty free-flow text box instead of a drop-down with all the zip codes in it.

I really appreciate any help or pointers regarding this..

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for [Finder](https://drupal.org/project/finder) module, it will display the autocomplete dropdown list to the users.

> Finder allows Drupal site administrators to create flexible faceted
>   search forms to find entities such as nodes or users based on the
>   values of fields and database attributes.
>   [image]

Comment: That looks awesome, thank you! I will certainly check it out